# Assign Data To Variable from eBay JSON Object

Tags: node.js, express, ebay-api

I'm experimenting with the eBay api and trying to get the value of the title from an object.

Here's view of what data looks like

[image]

I've tried the following code, with several variations, but I keep getting this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  ebay.findItemsByKeywords("iphone").then(data => {
    const newdata = JSON.parse(data);
    const title = newdata[0].searchResult.item.title;
    res.render("index", {
      title: title
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you share the full JSON in its raw form, like without beautifying it?

Comment: here you go https://www.pastiebin.com/5d67340322521

Comment: your `searchResult`, `item` and `title` are arrays, and I think you would want to use `newdata[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title[0]` instead.

Comment: thank you, i tried that and now getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

ok this did the trick

```
 const title = data[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title;
    res.render("index", {
      title: title
    });
```